# How to customize the line between tableViewCell in TableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

I've created an `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`. Between the view cells there are grew lines, but It's not fill width. I mean this lack a little bit at the lead. These are 2 option of separatorStyle is .none and .singleLine but I don't need them. I work with separatorInset but don't understand. I need change width of it, how can I?

I work with Xcode 9.0 and Swift.

Below is a screenshot that displays my screen:

[image]

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/table-view-separator-inset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your `tableView` and from Attribute Inspector change property of `Separator Inset`.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain What's different between your answer and the link suggested by @Rakesha Shastri --> https://useyourloaf.com/blog/table-view-separator-inset/

Comment: Many thanks for you help <3